Factorization and order of elements in splitting field
Example 4.4. Let $p=2$, $n=4$. Consider the polynomial $f=x^{2^{4}}-x=x^{16}-x$.
Then $\text{GF}(16)$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $\text{GF}(2)$. The irreducible factors of $f$ over $\text{GF}(2)$ have degrees 4, 2, and 1. A factorization of $f$ over $\text{GF}(2)$ is given by
$x^{16}-x = x(x-1)(x^{2}+x+1)(x^{4}+x+1)(x^{4}+x^{3}+1)(x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1)$.
Let $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ be roots of $x^{4}+x+1$, $x^{4}+x^{3}+1$, $x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1,$ respectively. $\text{GF}(16)$ is constructed as $\text{GF}(2)(\alpha), \text{GF}(2)(\beta)$ or $\text{GF}(2)(\gamma)$. It is straightforward to check that $o(\alpha)=o(\beta)=15$ in the cyclic group of units of the splitting field of $f$ over $\text{GF}(2)$. So both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are primitive elements of $\text{GF}(16)$.
On the other hand, from $\gamma^{{5}}-1=(1+\gamma+\gamma^{2}+\gamma^{3}+\gamma^{4})(\gamma-1)=0$, we can only conclude that the order of $\gamma$ divides 5, written as $o(\gamma)|5$. This implies $\gamma$ is not a primitive element. In other words, $\gamma$ generates a cyclic subgroup of order dividing 5 within $\text{GF}(16)^{\}$.
I came across this example while trying to study about finite fields in coding theory. I dont understand where every thing is coming from. I get that irreducible factors of f over Gf(2) must have degree 4,2 and 1 but I dont understand how they got the factorization given. Is this factorization unique?Also how did they conclude GF(16) is constructed as GF(2)(α),GF(2)(β) or GF(2)(γ). I also dont understand what they used to conclude o(α)=o(β)=15 and why o(γ)  is different from the other two.

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

Sorry about that. I have added the question above.

I dont understand where every thing is coming from. - all your questions are answered in chapters "finite fields", in books on abstract algebra, or in books on coding theory. Yes, the factorization in $F[x]$ is unique, and can be obtained by using the Berlekamp algorithm. Please use MathJax also in the last section of your text.

For the case of $x^4+x+1$ take a look at this old answer of mine. I denoted its zero by $\gamma$.

@JyrkiLahtonen, thank you for guiding me in that direction. That cleared up alot of my doubts.
